# C# winform panel not showing scrollbar

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar

**I've already seen similar questions but still could not get it to work**

I have the following controls on my `Form` (refer image):

```
A: a groupbox
B: another groupbox
C: a panel which contains A and B
```

Height of the panel is adjusted on window resize. I have tried using `Autoscroll = true` on the panel but the scrollbars won't show.

The groupbox `A` is anchored to `Top Left` and has dock `Top`. The groupbox B is anchored to Top Left`but has dock`Fill`.

Any idea why the scrollbar isn't showing ?? Also, What dock property should I give to new controls ( groupbox, maybe ), if I plan on adding more of them. I would want to show them one below the other.

[image]

Comment: the window will only show a scrollbar if the length/width exceeds currently shown size. If you not told your window to grow with control changes etc the control just goes off window

Comment: forget anchors, use the dock property in stead

Comment: @BugFinder please check the image attached (had forgotten to attach it along with the question). The controls are exceeding the panel height

Comment: Thanks @mrid however you havent shown in that that the window is set to grow or not..

Comment: If you use the dock propertys your controles will resize to fitt to the parent container. in this case no scroll bar will appear because they will never overflow. If you could Provide some more Informations an how you would like to build your UI I could help you setting it up.

Comment: @BugFinder sry, the window is resizable, and so is the panel. the panel grows with the window size

Comment: IMO, the usual Panel inside a Panel (with AutoScroll=true and Autosize=false, Dock=fill) works well and it's easy to handle even at design-time (if you want a Panel to show the scrollbars, not the form window).

Answer (score 0):

Make your GroupBoxes To dock Top both. and turn autoscroll on true for your panel. That way they will stack on each other expanding themselfs down and ignoring the panel height. Also set a minheight and minwidth for both so if the panel gets to small it will start so overflow and show the scrollbars.